# Git: Move changes for specific files from first repo to specific folder from second repo

Tags: git

I need to move changes from commit of one repo to another folder of another repo.

My structure:

```
Repo1:
    dir1:
        nested_dir1:
            file1
            file2

Repo2:
    dir2:
        file1
        file2
```

For Repo2:

```
git remote add repo1
```

My repos have different structure. But files(from `dir2` and `nested_dir1`) have the same name.

Changes in `file1` and `file2` from `repo1/dir1/nested_dir1` need to apply to `repo2/dir2`

I've tried to do it via format-patch:

```
git format-patch <sha> -- repo1/dir1/nested_dir1
```

But patch is not created. Probably because it does not find such a folder

Maybe someone knows, is it possible?

Comment: When you say repo, do you mean you have two `git` repo with their own `.git` folder? Or are these all under one `.git`

Comment: @astrochun 2 separate git setting. I use remote to connect them

Comment: Hmm, usually `remote` is intended for copies that will follow the same structure. That is if you merged changes from `repo1` into `repo2, it would create a `dir1` in  `repo2`. The commit that you have for that is unique to those paths. Is there a reason why the directory structure is as such?

Comment: Yes I have reason, I cannot change it. :(

Comment: Can you not create a new commit for this sync? If these repos are on GitHub, you could sync the two files together using GitHub Actions. Just a thought.

Comment: one repo from Gitlab second from Github

Comment: Could please clarify "new commit for this sync"?

Comment: Can you do: `cp Repo1/dir1/nested_dir1/file1 Repo2/dir2/file1 && git add Repo2/dir2/file1 && git commit -m "Update repo" && git push`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My way.

I'm working from `Repo2`:

```
git remote add repo1
```

Creating patch for commit from `Repo1` only for `nested_dir1` folder:

```
git format-patch -1 <sha> -- dir1/nested_dir1/
```

Appling patch for `dir2` from `Repo2`:

```
git am -p2 --directory='dir2' *.patch
```

`-p2` - remove `dir1/nested_dir1/` from path of changes

`--directory='dir2`' - add dir2 for path of changes

Done!